# Getting the source of an image from a user upload in JavaScript to use later

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I want the user to upload an image from their hard drive and be allowed to crop it, with the cropped image appearing through jQuery on the same page after the user has selected the two points on the image to crop between.

I got this function below from another Stack Overflow question, which allows an image that has been selected by the user to be displayed. This works fine but I'm having trouble getting the image source, which I will need later on.

```
function el(id){return document.getElementById(id);} // Get elem by ID

function readImage() {
    if ( this.files && this.files[0] ) {
        var FR= new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function(e) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.addEventListener("load", function() {
                var canvas = el('canvas');
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var width = img.naturalWidth;

                $.ajax({
                    url:"save_width.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{width:width},
                });

                canvas.width  = img.naturalWidth/2;
                canvas.height = img.naturalHeight/2;

                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth/2, img.naturalHeight/2);

            });
            img.src = e.target.result;
            var source = e.target.result;
            alert(source);
            $.ajax({
                url:"save_image.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{source:source},
            });
        };       
        FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
    }
}

el("fileUpload").addEventListener("change", readImage, false);
```

I thought that I could simply set the `e.target.result` to a variable (`source` in this instance) and then post that variable to a page where it could be set to a session variable and called again later. However, this gives me a data string that includes multiple occurrences of two slashes (//), which means it comments itself out when the code is run.

Is it possible to save something from this code to a variable that will allow me to display and manipulate the user's uploaded image later?

Comment: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: @AvrilAlejandro Thank you it works a treat. It's much simpler to use this instead of all the session variables I've been messing around with as well, so you've really improved my project's efficiency!